# Connecting Node.js to SQL Server Using IP Address

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I'm attempting to establish a connection from Node.js to SQL Server using an IP address instead of 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'. Here is my code:

```
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');

const config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: '123456',
    server: '172.20.10.1',
    database: 'coffee',
    options: {
        encrypt: true, 
    },
};

sql.connect(config)
    .then(pool => {
        console.log('Connected to SQL Server');
        return pool.request().query('SELECT * FROM coffee_info');
    })
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result.recordset);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('Error:', err);
    })
    .finally(() => {
        sql.close();
    });
```

This code works when using 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1', but I encounter errors when using an IP address like '172.20.10.1':

> Error: ConnectionError: Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
>
> Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired,Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
>
> at PrivateConnection.callback2 (C:\Users\Nguyen Duc Thang\StudioProjects\coffee\lib\backend\node_modules\mssql\lib\msnodesqlv8\connection-pool.js:46:17)
> at Immediate. (C:\Users\Nguyen Duc Thang\StudioProjects\coffee\lib\backend\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\connection.js:43:14)
> at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:476:21) {
> code: undefined
> }

I am attempting to use an IP address for a virtual Android environment. I'm seeking guidance on how to correctly configure the connection or any potential steps needed to establish a successful connection to SQL Server using an IP address in this context. Any advice or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "*because the target machine actively refused it*"  There is either no process listening on port 1433 (default port for sql server) on that machine or the firewall on that machine doesn't allow connections on port 1433. Check your firewall, check if the SQL Server is running and also check if it is configured for TCP/IP connections and if it allows remote connections.

Comment: Is the NodeJS machine actually in the same network as the SQL Server? The  172.16.0.0/12 CIDR block (172.16.0.0-172.31.255.255) is a private network that is considered to be non-routable by other networks. i.e.: network routers won't attempt to forward traffic to/from it.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning if the "target machine actively refused it" a route to the target has been found.